# Telethon event handler not firing when used in an asyncio task with another task

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio, telethon

I'm trying to get two tasks with infinite loops running simultaneously. One of them involves running the Telethon client indefinitely, the other involves a while loop in order to check for connections on a socket.

The socket task works fine, I can create the socket and connect a client to it. However the other task, which runs the Telethon client, doesn't seem to respond to the NewMessage event when I fire off an event from my telegram account. I've seen this working prior, so I know it's not the client itself, my account or the connection to it.

I assume this is just an issue with me not understanding how the asyncio package works. Could someone please point me in the right direction to understanding how I can have both of my tasks run concurrently and respond to both my socket and my message events.

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def onMessage(event):
    # print(event.raw_text) # Event handler implementation
    

async def run_client():
    await client.start()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()
    # async with client:
        # await client.run_until_disconnected()
        # await client.loop.run_forever()

async def socket_listener():
    global client_socket
    while True:
        # Accept a client connection
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Client connected:", client_address)


async def main():    
    asyncio.gather(run_client(), socket_listener())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `socket_listener` has no `await`, which means it will never yield control back to the `asyncio` event loop. If the `asyncio` event loop doesn't get control back, it will be unable to progress your other tasks.

In other words, `server_socket.accept()` is blocking the entire thread.

You should use an `asyncio` alternative to listen to connections. See the documentation for [`asyncio` Streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html), in particular, `asyncio.start_server`, which is an `async` alternative.

Comment: I replaced the server_socket with your suggestion of using start_server and it's worked pretty much first time with very minor changes. Thank you for your suggestion, works great.